# How to migrate data from teradata to GCS using Apache Beam

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, teradata, apache-beam

Which jar files could we use? How will we connect to Teradata from Apache Beam and read the tables?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Java SDK, you can use `JdbcIO` connector to read data from Teradata and `FileIO` to write it to GCS.

Comment: I did it using JdbcIo in python. But I am now getting the classnotfound exception for the jdbc driver_class_name "com.teradata.jdbc.TeraDriver" .

Comment: Python jdbcio is a multi-language connector (uses Java JDBCIO underneath) so you have to start an expansion service with the correct jars. There's more info here: https://beam.apache.org/documentation/sdks/python-multi-language-pipelines/

Comment: @chamikara Thanks for replying. I want to use a default expansion service, so as given in :https://beam.apache.org/releases/pydoc/2.35.0/apache_beam.io.jdbc.html , I installed the Java Runtime and made sure that java command is available. But still after that when I run the code below 
with beam.Pipeline() as p:
  result = ( p | 'Read from jdbc' >> ReadFromJdbc(
          table_name='staff', driver_class_name='com.mysql.jdbc.Driver',
          jdbc_url='jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/example',
          username='root',  password='root',
      ))
I am getting the ClassNotFound Exception.